# SQLite Manager INSERT INTO fails but produces no error

Tags: sqlite, sqlitemanager

I have a SQLite DB that has a table:

```
table: import_info
   Columns: First_Name, Last_Name, Payroll_ID, ... other columns not used

tabel employees
   Columns: name, employee_num
```

I want to select the unique names and payroll_id's from the first table into the employees table as `name` and `employee_num`.

If I select the table in SQLite Manager and run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Last_Name || ' ' || First_Name AS name, Payroll_ID 
AS employee_num 
FROM import_info
```

I get the results perfectly. But if I try:

```
INSERT INTO employees (name, employee_num)
SELECT DISTINCT Last_Name || ' ' || First_Name AS name, Payroll_ID 
AS employee_num 
FROM import_info
```

I get nothing. No error, nothing happens.

Comment: Did you then try `select * from employees`?  The `insert` doesn't really return anything.

Comment: Yes, it returns all the columns in `employees`, with no data since that table is empty. The import_info table has 9,000+ rows, each employee having many entries. Thus the `Distinct`.

Comment: I think I might see the problem. The table structure is: `CREATE TABLE "employees" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar, "employee_num" integer, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)` so I am not supplying created_at or updated_at. Any idea how to just supply every row with a dummy value for those two columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply values as:

```
INSERT INTO employees(name, employee_num, created_at, updated_at)
    SELECT DISTINCT Last_Name || ' ' || First_Name AS name, Payroll_ID,
           datetime('now'), datetime('now')
    FROM import_info
```

I'm surprised, however, that leaving out the values doesn't result in an error.  Perhaps something is suppressing the errors.

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect. I was googling around for the syntax but it was stumping me on how to phrase it so that google would give the answer. If I messed up the syntax it would have no problem throwing an error. Odd that it doesn't throw one in the case I outlined.